# with keyboard tab key tabindex element is not showing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hi i want to show edit icon with `tab key press`(keyboard accessibility) and once enter key is pressed from keyboard alert must come.

**expected solution (can be either of below one):**

**1. best:** on tab button press, directly highlight the edit icon on list and  on enter key press `alert must come`  -  1 step

**2. Ok:** on tab button press, highlight list item then on next tab press highlight the edit icon and on enter key press  `alert must come` - 2 step

**Below image shows non working demo**

[image]

Below is what i have tried:

```js
function editClicked(){
   alert('tab and enter key pressed')
}
```

```css
ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

li{
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  margin-top:20px;
}

li{
  border:1px solid yellow;
}

li:hover{
  border:1px solid red;
}   

li span.edit{
  visibility:hidden;
}

ul li:hover span.edit{
   visibility:visible;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li tabindex="0">
     <span>content</span>
     <span onclick="editClicked()" class="edit" tabindex="0" ><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
   
    <li tabindex="0">
     <span>content</span>
     <span onclick="editClicked()" class="edit" tabindex="0"><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
    
   <li tabindex="0">
     <span>content</span>
     <span onclick="editClicked()" class="edit" tabindex="0"><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: its difficult to understand what you wanted to achieve explain a bit more about your expected result

Comment: @AmirRahman it is quite simple , press tab in your keyboard and see edit icon is not showing

Comment: I don't know dispite of so many views (100+) still i'm not getting the answer. is the problem so difficult. I thought it is a normal workflow for everyone.

Comment: its not difficult in logic it just need some custom work to do as your requirement it is more of a work post and Stack Overflow mainly focus on helping people with their code where they got stucked and need help or need some knowledge on particular topic

Comment: also i wanted to add that in your current code the main problem is when you press tab second time it loses focus from parent and jump to edit button in between this time the edit button is already losing visibility as a result edit button is not getting focused

Comment: @AmirRahman whatever the reason might be there , i don't know the solution. i just need a help

Comment: You need JavaScript to do so

Comment: @EaBengaluru have you checked my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Fixing your `tabindexes` and adding a `keydown` event to the document made the 2nd expected solution possible.

```js
function editClicked(){
   alert('editClicked clicked')
}     

document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
    if (e.code != "Enter") return;
    let a = document.activeElement; // active element
    if (a.className == "edit") {
        editClicked();
    }
}
```

```css
ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

li{
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  margin-top:20px;
}

li{
  border:1px solid yellow;
}

li:focus{
  border:1px solid red;
}   

li .edit{
  opacity: 0;
}

ul li:focus .edit, ul li .edit:focus {
   opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li tabindex="1">
     <span>content</span>
     <span tabindex="2" onclick="editClicked()" class="edit"><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
   
    <li tabindex="3">
     <span>content</span>
     <span tabindex="4" onclick="editClicked()" class="edit"><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
    
   <li tabindex="5">
     <span>content</span>
     <span tabindex="6" onclick="editClicked()" class="edit"><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: now tabbing works fine on `li` but still edit icon is not being focused on 2nd tab, could you please check that

Comment: that is why i have added alert in my code

Comment: @EaBengaluru I've made edits to my answer. Also please don't bombard me with comments.

Comment: not working as expected . i don't want to show edit icon always. on hover only i want to show it.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can control the visibility of the edit icon using the **CSS Opacity** style
2. You only need to set tab-index for the edit icons

**Solution**

```
li .edit{
 opacity: 0;
}

ul li:focus-within .edit, ul li:hover .edit {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```js
function editClicked(){
   alert('editClicked clicked')
   document.activeElement.blur()
}     

document.addEventListener('keydown', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
    if (e.code != "Enter") return;
    let a = document.activeElement; // active element
    if (a.className == "edit") {
        editClicked();
    }
}
```

```css
ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

li{
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  margin-top:20px;
}

li{
  border:1px solid yellow;
}

li:focus{
  border:1px solid red;
}   

li .edit{
 opacity: 0;
}

ul li:focus-within .edit, ul li:hover .edit {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>
     <span>content</span>
     <span tabindex="1" onclick="editClicked()" class="edit"><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
   
    <li>
     <span>content</span>
     <span tabindex="2" onclick="editClicked()" class="edit"><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
    
   <li>
     <span>content</span>
     <span tabindex="3" onclick="editClicked()" class="edit"><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
<ul>
```

Comment: that's great but when i hover over the list with mouse `edit icon` is not showing. it must show

Comment: Ok. Updated the CSS

Comment: @EaBengaluru If this answer solves your question, you may consider marking it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Option 1: fill color!

```js
function editClicked(){
   alert('tab and enter key pressed')
}
function handleEnter(e){
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
      document.activeElement.click();
    }
 }
```

```css
ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

li{
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  margin-top:20px;
}

li{
  border:1px solid yellow;
 background-color:#fff;
}

li:hover{
  border:1px solid red;
}   

li span svg.editc{
  fill: #fff;
}

ul li:hover span svg.editc{
   fill: black;
}
.edit:focus .editc{
 fill: black;
}
.edit{
height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body onkeypress="handleEnter(event)">
<ul>
   <li>
     <span>content</span>
     <span onclick="editClicked()" class="edit" tabindex="0" ><svg class="editc" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
   
    <li>
     <span>content</span>
     <span onclick="editClicked()" class="edit" tabindex="0"><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="editc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
    
   <li>
     <span>content</span>
     <span onclick="editClicked()" class="edit" tabindex="0"><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="editc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
<ul>
```

Option 2: Opacity!

```js
function editClicked(){
   alert('tab and enter key pressed')
}
function handleEnter(e){
    var keycode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if (keycode == '13') {
      document.activeElement.click();
    }
 }
```

```css
ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

li{
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  margin-top:20px;
}

li{
  border:1px solid yellow;
 background-color:#fff;
}

li:hover{
  border:1px solid red;
}   

li span svg.editc{
  opacity: 0;
}

ul li:hover span svg.editc{
   opacity: 1;
}
.edit:focus .editc{
 opacity: 1;
}
.edit{
height: 1em;
}
```

```html
<body onkeypress="handleEnter(event)">
<ul>
   <li>
     <span>content</span>
     <span onclick="editClicked()" class="edit" tabindex="0" ><svg class="editc" width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
   
    <li>
     <span>content</span>
     <span onclick="editClicked()" class="edit" tabindex="0"><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="editc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
    
   <li>
     <span>content</span>
     <span onclick="editClicked()" class="edit" tabindex="0"><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="editc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
<ul>
```

UPDATE: fix tabindex to 0;

Answer (score 0):

Hope i understand your question correct. I removed `tabindex` from spans and added notes inside code.

```js
function editClicked(){
   alert('tab and enter key pressed')
}
/***********************/
// iterate list items
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(element => {
// on focus event:
  element.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    // color borders
    this.classList.add('liHover');
    // show current pencil
    this.querySelectorAll('.edit')[0].classList.add('editHover');
    // listen to keyboard
    this.addEventListener('keypress',editThis);
  });
// on blur event - do the opposite.  
  element.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    this.classList.remove('liHover');
    this.querySelectorAll('.edit')[0].classList.remove('editHover');
    this.removeEventListener('keypress',editThis);
  });
});
// this will activate when list item is on focus
function editThis(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') { editClicked(); }
}
```

```css
ul{
 list-style:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

li{
  width:100%;
  height:80px;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  margin-top:20px;
}

li{
  border:1px solid yellow;
}
.liHover,
li:hover{
  border:1px solid red;
}   

li span.edit{
  visibility:hidden;
}
.editHover,
ul li:hover span.edit{
   visibility:visible!important;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li tabindex="0">
     <span>content</span>
     <span onclick="editClicked()" class="edit"><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
   
    <li tabindex="0">
     <span>content</span>
     <span onclick="editClicked()" class="edit"><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
    
   <li tabindex="0">
     <span>content</span>
     <span onclick="editClicked()" class="edit"><svg  width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bi bi-pen-fill"><path  fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.498.795l.149-.149a1.207 1.207 0 1 1 1.707 1.708l-.149.148a1.5 1.5 0 0 1-.059 2.059L4.854 14.854a.5.5 0 0 1-.233.131l-4 1a.5.5 0 0 1-.606-.606l1-4a.5.5 0 0 1 .131-.232l9.642-9.642a.5.5 0 0 0-.642.056L6.854 4.854a.5.5 0 1 1-.708-.708L9.44.854A1.5 1.5 0 0 1 11.5.796a1.5 1.5 0 0 1 1.998-.001z"></path></svg></span>
   </li>
<ul>
```